# Gibberish when writing to file

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to read a file, and then write it back to the same file with a space between each character, and one set uppercase and one set normal.

I can write either set normally, but I can't write both of them normally.

Here is my code

```
import string
f = open('text.txt', 'r+')
file = f.read()
file = file.translate(None, string.whitespace)
file = file.translate(None, string.punctuation)
file = ' '.join(file)
file2 = file.upper()
f.seek(0)
f.write(file)
f.flush()
f.write(file2)
f.close()
```

Yet, sadly this does not work. When opening it up in notepad, its all gibberish. When reading it a second time in python, it sees both sets of strings perfectly, and then gibberish until an error. For example:

```
 Y A L E T T E R S A Y I N G ô C    ƒ▬s ► É☺↨ ░☺≡≡≡ ≡≡≡                
 ☺☺☺        Ç>      ☺   ☺   ☺               ▼ ë☺                            ☺
```

Then ending should be "trouble than it's worth"

So half way through everything just going to gibberish instead of writing like it should.

This happens even if I don't write  to file.

```
print file returns perfect string
print file2 returns perfect string
temp = file + file2
print temp returns gibberish part of the way through
```

So why the hell is it returning gibberish, and what can I do to fix this?

Comment: What is your original input?

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the exact contents of the input file, and told us your Python version.

Comment: I've actually resolved this. I just needed a flush() after the second file write. I'm not even sure why.

Comment: Am I the only one feeling opening the file for read and append and than essentially erasing it is somewhat wrong? What if you close the file handler, than reopen it with `"w"` mode and write to it?

Comment: It really wouldn't be easy to provide the original input as its over a thousand characters. Same with output.

Comment: @JOHN That seems like a waste of file I/O's. the biggest bottleneck in any system. why open and write to a file multiple times for the same exact operation? Memory is faster then hard disks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to *truncate* your file before writing to it again:

```
f.seek(0)
f.truncate()
```

Comment: why? you can also just overwrite it partially.

Comment: I suspect it could make a difference here. Just to verify, this is on Python 2 or Python 3?